# Scala Option.orElse equivalent for Java Optional

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, monads, option-type

`Option` has the following method defined:

```
def orElse[B >: A](alternative : => scala.Option[B]) : scala.Option[B]
```

I'm trying to find something similar in Java 8. I came to this expression:

```
private String userId() {
        return user.map(User::getUsername)
                .orElse(this.userId.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new));
    }
```

Where `user` and `userId` are both `Optional`'s, but somehow this crashes with `RuntimeException` even if `user` is defined.
Is there something more functional in Java then just starting making conditionals on `Optional`'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Optional.or](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) method introduced in Java 9:

```
public Optional<T> or​(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
private String userId() {
    return user.map(User::getUsername)
            .orElseGet(() -> this.userId.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new));
}
```

When you use normal `orElse`, its parameter is executed before execution of `orElse` itself, so `orElse` can just return it, but cannot decide whether execute it or not. Using `orElseGet` you create a lambda which is executed only when the `Optional` is empty.

Comment: it doesn't return an optional back :(